# How do I check if my app is installed on the device using my web site?

Tags: android, ios, web

I have a website and an app to listen to radio online. I would like to verify that the person who has accessed my site already has the radio app installed, how do I do this verification?

example: [I need this!](http://www.collegemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Smart-App-Banner-Screenshot1.png)

Comment: Don't you think it would be a bit insecure and compromising your privacy if any website could check your apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you want a [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html). There are multiple Android equivalents; search for Android Smart App Banner.